# Is there a way to use Dex or Acrobatics for Trip?

Tags: skills, pathfinder-2e, combat-maneuver, trip

I think I have seen a way to Trip without investing in Strength.

Right now I can only find [Tumbling Opportunist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1878), which requires 10th level and can only be used once per minute, and [Improved Knockdown](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=403&ArchLevel=12), which has even higher level, and has one more feat as prerequisite.
(Telekinetic Maneuver uses your spellcasting ability modifier, but most characters can use it less frequently than Tumbling Opportunist.)

Is there an earlier solution that does not need Strength, but is usable at will?

Comment: Title question asks about triping with dex/acrobatics, but the body question asks about tripping without strength, which of these two questions are you really asking? The answers will be very different.

Comment: @Ruse, the answers will be very similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Assurance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=756)

A level 1 skill feat that allows you to use a static number just based on your proficiency in a skill rather than adding all the normal modifiers together including your ability modifier.

This static result is usually too low against bosses/equivalently-leveled enemies or higher, but it can be very useful when you're taking a massive penalty due to something like the Multiple Attack Penalty on the 2nd or 3rd attack of a round, or if you know a specifically weak save that the target possesses.

### Investigator

[Athletic Strategist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1452) as a level 2 investigator feat allows the core mechanic of using Intelligence to attack their studied target to apply on Athletics skill checks like Trip.

This only works with investigator as a class, specifically called out in the multiclass archetype feat [Investigator's Strategem](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1846), and it also requires Intelligence.

### Wolf Stance

[Wolf Drag](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=457) as a level 6 monk feat or level 8 martial artist allows your finesse wolf jaw unarmed attack to also knock a target prone on a hit. Technically not a Trip but roughly equivalent results for two or three feats.

### [Blade of the Rabbit Prince](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=836)

This weapon from the harrowed realm allows the user to use Thievery in place of an Athletics check to Trip. It's 15th level and rare so getting access is likely to be difficult, but it could theoretically be used much earlier.

### Consumables

A [*whip feather token*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=244) level 9 consumable creates a dancing magical whip that attempts to Trip your foes instead of just attacking them. Incredibly expensive for when it would be useful, and the static bonus will make this non-viable in practice by the time it becomes roughly at-will.

The level 4 [trip snare](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=347) more directly knocks creatures to the ground, but this does require set-up beforehand and the Snare Crafting feat. Still, there's a lot of support for crafting snares more quickly and freely a few times per day in the ranger class and in the [snarecrafter](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=78)/[trapsmith](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=111) archetypes, including setting the DC to your class DC rather than just the default level 4 DC.

### Your GM Could Allow It

> If the GM deems it appropriate for a certain situation, however, they might have you use a different ability modifier for a skill check or when determining your skill DC.

While the [finesse](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=179) trait on a weapon isn't enough to replace Strength with Dexterity for the Athletics skill check, there is a specific [exception](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=172) for GMs to allow a different ability modifier for a skill check if they feel it's appropriate.

An example of a case where this might be is given in another rule, [Using Stealth with Other Senses](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=414)

> In some cases, rolling a Dexterity-based Stealth skill check to Sneak doesn’t make the most sense. For example, when facing a creature that can detect heartbeats, a PC trying to avoid being detected might meditate to slow their heart rate, using Wisdom instead of Dexterity as the ability modifier for the Stealth check.

In line with this, your GM might have you use Dexterity to Trip when attacking with a finesse + trip weapon such as the [kukri](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=56), or with  a ranged trip weapon like the [bola](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=123).

Answer (score -4):

### You can do that at lvl 1

The key is using a weapon with both the [finesse](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=179) and the [trip](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=196) traits (like the spiked chain, the whip, the bladed scarf...).

Finesse:

> You can use your Dexterity modifier instead of your Strength modifier on attack rolls using this melee weapon. You still use your Strength modifier when calculating damage.

Trip:

> You can use this weapon to Trip with the Athletics skill even if you don't have a free hand. This uses the weapon's reach (if different from your own) and adds the weapon's item bonus to attack rolls as an item bonus to the Athletics check. If you critically fail a check to Trip using the weapon, you can drop the weapon to take the effects of a failure instead of a critical failure.

The trip trait lets you use this weapon to perform the Trip action. As the Trip action has the attack trait it is an attack, and as such it is an "attack roll using this melee weapon" and the finesse trait applies.

Some people claim that a Trip is not an actual attack: they are wrong. It is not a strike, but finesse doesn't only apply to strikes: it applies to all attacks "using this melee weapon". Also it doesn't magically lets you do Athletics with your dex while unarmed because your fists usually don't have the trip trait.

Comment: The Trip action calls for a *skill check*, while Finesse only modifies *attack rolls*, so this doesn't work.

Comment: The [FAQ](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq) has a section in the Core Rulebook Errata, page 446 on Attack Rolls that clarifies this further. Trip is an attack that requires a skill check instead of an attack roll as @Ruse mentions.

Comment: This may not be at all helpful, depending on how the RAW/RAI discussion goes in the Pathfinder space, but someone asked Greg Everham this question on Facebook:
https://www.facebook.com/groups/2ndEdPFPlaytest/permalink/230937247584504/?comment_id=230940117584217&reply_comment_id=230943007583928